# dJango order by list of conditions

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-views

Let's say I have a list of 3 conditions: `conditionA`, `conditionB`, `conditionC`.

I want to be able to sort my queryset so that items matching `conditionA` & `conditionB` & `conditionC` appears first, then `conditionA` & `conditionB`, then `conditionA` & `conditionC` etc. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`order_by()` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#order-by)) will respect the order you put the arguments in.

**EDIT**

This is kind of funky, but doing something like this should give you what you need:

You could sort it like this:

```
funky_queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(name="john")
funky_queryset |= MyModel.objects.filter(other_condition)
...
```

`funky_queryset` will be in the order of which you add more items to it. The `|=` operator lets you combine querysets.

Another example:

Pretend like you have this queryset that you want to sort:

```
[<James Bond >, <Bart Simpson >, <John Jacob >, <John Stamos >, <Max Payne >]
```

Let's also say `conditionA` is that you want to have `name="john"`, `conditionB` is that you want to have `name="max"`, conditionC is that you want all of the others. You can do it like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

sorted_queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(name="john")  # conditionA
sorted_queryset |= MyModel.object.filter(name="max")  # conditionB
sorted_queryset |= MyModel.objects.exclude(Q(name="john") | Q(name="max"))  # conditionC
```

The result would be `[<John Jacob>, <John Stamos>, <Max Payne>, <Bart Simpson>, <James Bond>]`

Comment: Thank you, would it work if my condition is like `name='john'`?

Comment: You will probably want to use a filter for that. You can order by the name alphabetically.

Comment: I need it to be a list sorted so that the objects with `name=john` will appear first, then the rest comes :\

Comment: THank you, but i'm not looking to filter it, I'm looking to sort the queryset. Should I just do a filter then subtract that from the list of all?

Comment: @FriGate by filtering them sequentially like that, you are building a queryset that is in the order you want.

Comment: Yea, but I also need the other items which doesn't match it :\

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Okay then